# Struggling to remember something small

Tags: complex-numbers

Evaluate $(1+i)^{11}$.

I got $(1+i)^{11} = 2^{11/2} [\cos (11/4π) + i\sin(11/4π)]$

I don't know how the angle change to $3/4\pi$

That is:
$$2^{11/2} [\cos(3/4π) + i\sin(3/4π)]$$

I think I have forgotten

Comment: Hint: $\frac{11}{4}\pi=2 \pi + \frac{3}{4}\pi$

Answer (score 0):

$$(1+i)^{11}=(1+i)^{10}\times(1+i)$$
$$(2i)^5\times(1+i)=32i(1+i)=32(-1+i)$$

Comment: So how did the angle become 3/4π?

Comment: There is no need to make the angle 3/4π. The method I have used is most convenient here.

Comment: So if i decide to use  (1+i)^11 without breaking it into 32(-1+i) i will be correct with an angle of 11/4π right? That is using the de moive theorem

Comment: @AshalleySamuel, I can't understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos(x)=\cos(x + 2\pi n) $ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, it is a periodic function, as is $\sin$. So a complex number with an argument of $11\pi/4$ is just the same as one with argument $3\pi/4$, you can change it by integer multiples of $2\pi$. The complex number lies in the second quadrant (top left)

Comment: Oh thanks...i really appreciate.